# How would you build a media equipment tracking system in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services

Currently I have a standard List application built in share point that we add, and update the list items when someone signs out and returns a piece of media equipment.

I am looking to improve this with a few features

1. Dropdown of all equipment instead of typing in it's code
2. Once selected that dropdown will also populate the aux items that come with that kit, like power cords etc.
3. Have a print view showing everything they have, as the person loaning out needs to sign a release
4. View of everything that is out at any given input of time

Phase 2

1. Notification system to Admins of over due equipment
2. Ability to run reports against the data

Phase 3

1. Some kind of ecommerce to charge late fees

Any ideas or software packages even that could do this?

Would this require a solid ASPX Developer?

We are wanting to stick inside shareppoint as it is a secured location that can be accessed by the proper staff anywhere in the building to check on and loan out equipment.

Thanks for you time
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find my replies within:

> Dropdown of all equipment instead of typing in it's code
>
> Once selected that dropdown will also populate the aux items that come
>   with that kit, like power cords etc.

You can use a lookup column and populate rest of the fields according to the dropdown selection.

> Have a print view showing everything they have, as the person loaning
>   out needs to sign a release
>   View of everything that is out at any given input of time

You can create some specific views on the list and use http://spprintlist.codeplex.com/ to perform the printing job for you!

> Notification system to Admins of over due equipment 
>   Ability to run reports against the data 
>   You can attach a workflow to the list, which will send notifications to admin upon date overdue.
>
> Some kind of ecommerce to charge late fees

Add one extra field to the list holding the late fee, and let workflow to calculate this fee according to the overdue date.

> Any ideas or software packages even that could do this?

I would say, SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio would suffice.

> Would this require a solid ASPX Developer?

Developing this will definitely require some understanding of List and Workflows development

Comment: All very good comments, now to get on a PC so I can actually open the SharePoint Designer.